# Warning on Connecting to MongoDB with a Node server

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

### Connecting with MongoDB native driver

I wrote following code to connect mongodb through native driver which has been install with `npm install mongodb --save`

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";

const dbName = "game-of-thrones";
let db;

MongoClient.connect(
url,
 { useNewUrlParser: true },
  (err, client) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

  db = client.db(dbName);
   console.log(`Connected MongoDB: ${url}`);
   console.log(`Database: ${dbName}`);
  }
);
```

When I write on the terminal `node server.js` I got following error

> (node:3500) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>   Connected MongoDB: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>   Database: game-of-thrones

The database is connected, but how can I get rid out from the warning

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Check your mongo version

```
 mongo --version
```

If you are using version >= 3.1.0 change you mongo connection file to ->

```
 MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDB", {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
 })
```

For details about the `useUnifiedTopology` option added in 3.2.1, see https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/tag/v3.2.1

Comment: for people coming across this in future, will be enabled by default in v4+, currently latest version if v6

Answer (score 10):

My advice is to leave it as it is (maybe place a warning). The `useUnifiedTopology: true` option does not work correctly.

More precisely, in the event of a loss of connection to the DBMS, it will never be restored. Current version 3.3.3 does not solve this problem.

[Check this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-2147?jql=text%20~%20%22useUnifiedTopology%22)

Comment: This issue is shown as fixed in driver version 3.3.5, so this should no-longer be a problem.

Comment: @davidm_uk can confirm, answer is no longer relevant. Won't down-vote because it was both relevant and correct at the time of its posting.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error and resolved using the below template.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const client = new MongoClient(uri, {useUnifiedTopology: true});

client.connect().then((client)=>{
    var db = client.db('db_name')
    db.collection('collection_name').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(result);
    })
})
```

This worked for me. and now it's not showing any DepricationWarning.

Answer (score 3):

**I want to add to this thread that it may also have to do with other dependencies.**

For instance, nothing I updated or set for NodeJS, MongoDB or Mongoose were the issue - however - `connect-mongodb-session` had been updated and starting slinging the same error. The solution, in this case, was to simply rollback the version of `connect-mongodb-session` from version `2.3.0` to `2.2.0`.

UPDATE: The issue is now fixed in `connect-mongodb-session@2.3.1`.

[image]

Comment: This is fixed in version 2.3.1 Yay!

Comment: Great call-out. Some people may not think to check their dependencies

Answer (score 1):

This is what made it work for me.

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/blogdb', {useUnifiedTopology: true} , (err, client) =>
{
  if (err) throw err;
  const db = client.db('blogdb');
  const collection = db.collection('posts');
  const users = db.collection('users');
  app.locals.collection = collection;
  app.locals.users = users;

});
```

This is the same exact code I had before where I was getting the same deprecation message. The only difference is I haven't added the 'useUnifiedTopology: true' line.

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/blogdb', (err, client) =>
{
  if (err) throw err;
  const db = client.db('blogdb');
  const collection = db.collection('posts');
  const users = db.collection('users');
  app.locals.collection = collection;
  app.locals.users = users;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah i got the same issue , the database was connected successfully but i used to face with warning message of deprecating warning. here are some  short tips i used to handle it  i hope it will help you

```
mongoose.connect(
  database,
  {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30061395)

Answer (score -1):

Replace `yourdbname` with your variable or just link of your `mongodb`..

```
 mongoose.connect(yourdbname, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })
  .then(console.log("mongodb connected successfully...."))
  .catch(err =>console.log(err));
```

Comment: User wants to know about Native Mongo client