# Server Discovery And Monitoring engine is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose with my Node.js app and this is my configuration:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true,
   useCreateIndex: true,
   useFindAndModify: false
}).then(()=>{
    console.log(`connection to database established`)
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(`db error ${err.message}`);
    process.exit(-1)
})
```

but in the console it still gives me the warning:

> DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

What is the problem? I was not using `useUnifiedTopology` before but now it shows up in the console. I added it to the config but it still gives me this warning, why? I do not even use `MongoClient`.

### Edit

As Felipe Plets answered there was a problem in Mongoose and they fixed this bug in later versions. So you can solve problem by updating mongoose version.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

**Update**

Mongoose 5.7.1 was release and seems to fix the issue, so setting up the `useUnifiedTopology` option work as expected.

```js
mongoose.connect(mongoConnectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
```

**Original answer**

I was facing the same issue and decided to deep dive on Mongoose code: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/search?q=useUnifiedTopology&unscoped_q=useUnifiedTopology

Seems to be an option added on version 5.7 of Mongoose and not well documented yet. I could not even find it mentioned in the library history https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md

According to a comment in the code:

> - @param {Boolean} [options.useUnifiedTopology=false] False by default. Set to `true` to opt in to the MongoDB driver's replica set and sharded cluster monitoring engine.

There is also an issue on the project GitHub about this error: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8156

In my case I don't use Mongoose in a replica set or sharded cluster and though the option should be false. But if false it complains the setting should be true. Once is true it still don't work, probably because my database does not run on a replica set or sharded cluster.

I've downgraded to 5.6.13 and my project is back working fine. So the only option I see for now is to downgrade it and wait for the fix to update for a newer version.

Comment: i thought the same (downgrade version), I am using mlab clusters so maybe is the reason why warning does not dissapear?

Comment: there is a bug in latest mongoose `5.7.7` if you use `createConnection()` instead of `connect()`, like `mongoose.createConnection(conString, { useUnifiedTopology: true })`. `useUnifiedTopology` won't be taken in consideration and you will still get the warning. event with `mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true)` i still get the warning.

Comment: Warning still persist after downgrading to  5.6.13

Comment: I'm getting that error using the native MongoDB driver!

Comment: Here we have all the deprecated options:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html

Comment: This is what worked for me:
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
mongoose.connect( 'mongo_connection_string', { useNewUrlParser: true })

Comment: I have Mongoose 5.11.12 with the desired option useUnifiedTopology = true, but the error won't go away.

Answer (score 35):

In mongoDB, they deprecated current server and engine monitoring package, so you need to use new server and engine monitoring package. So you just use

> { useUnifiedTopology:true }

```
mongoose.connect("paste db link", {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
```

Comment: if you read my question, i mentioned there that i added `useUnifiedTopology: true` in my configuration and it still shows me warning

Comment: I had this problem and I also add `useUnifiedTopology: true` but still the same message is coming on the console.

Comment: For anyone getting the message still, try calling `mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true)` before mongoose.connect.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. You just have to put "useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true" together inside a pair of { }. I didn't use "useCreateIndex: true" though, but it gives me some idea. dev4life's way also works.

Comment: mongoose
.connect("db conn url", { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, })
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected!'))
.catch(err => { err => console.log(err) })

this is what worked for me

Comment: I installed the newer version of a mongoose but the error was still the same. I kept on looking and find out that, it was because of the Network Access. You should allow access from anywhere. Go to the network access and change it to access from anywhere.

Answer (score 16):

This solved my problem.

```
 const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

 const client = new MongoClient(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this is mongoose question, and i am not using mongoclient

Comment: @iLiA You are welcome. Yes I know. But this answer may be of help to someone, since I found your question exactly by title topic and not by content (and the content of your question is very close to general information about MongoClient)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As mentioned by you I landed up here due the error mentioned while working with mongoclient and not mongoose, helps!

Answer (score 5):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Tododb', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Will remove following errors:-

(node:7481) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

(node:7481) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Comment: Also make sure to add `useUnifiedTopology: true` to all the dependencies that uses mongoDB, in my case I was using `wiston-mongodb` I had to add it in the option as well

`winston.add(new winston.transports.MongoDB({ db: config.get('db'), options: { useUnifiedTopology: true } }));`

Comment: @GaelMusikingala this was my problem. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @GaelMusikingala, Thanks for saving my life. ❤️ 

Answer (score 4):

Well, recently I was facing the same issue. I went throught this [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#useunifiedtopology) and found the solution.

Update your mongodb connection instance as follows and set `useUnifiedTopology` separately as follows below -

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useCreateIndex: true,
   useFindAndModify: false
}).then(()=>{
    console.log(`connection to database established`)
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(`db error ${err.message}`);
    process.exit(-1)
});

mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
```

Note: I'm using `node@16.4.0` and `mongoose@5.13.1`

Comment: Can confirm. This is what it took to get it working for me

Answer (score 3):

You Can Try async await

```js
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(<database url>, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        });
        console.log("MongoDB Conected")
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Use {useUnifiedTopology: true}

Answer (score 3):

Add the **useUnifiedTopology** option and set it to **true**.

Set other 3 configuration of the *mongoose.connect* options which will deal with other remaining **DeprecationWarning**.

This configuration works for me!

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name';
mongoose.connect(
    url, 
    { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: false
    }
)
```

This will solve 4 **DeprecationWarning**.

1. Current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
2. Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { 
   useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
3. Collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
4. DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#-findandmodify-.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to avoid that error

```
MongoClient.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code includes createConnetion for some reason (In my case I'm using GridFsStorage),
try adding the following to your code:

```
    options: {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
```

just after file, like this:

```
    const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: mongodbUrl,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }
                const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
                const fileInfo = {
                    filename: filename,
                    bucketName: 'uploads'
                };
                resolve(fileInfo);
            });
        });
    },
    options: {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
})
```

If your case looks like mine, this will surely solve your issue.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

For folks using `MongoClient` try this:

```
MongoClient.connect(connectionurl, 
  {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true},  callback() {
```

For mongoose:

```
mongoose.connect(connectionurl, 
         {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true}).then(()=>{
```

Remove other connectionOptions

Comment: I admitted that i am not using mongoClient

Answer (score 1):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Edureka',{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (error)=> {
    const connectionStatus = !error ? 'Success': 'Error Connecting to database';
    console.log(connectionStatus);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to run your mongod command and keep the server running. If not, you will still be seeing this error.

I attach you my code:

```js
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
    const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

    const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
    const databaseName = 'task-manager'

    MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, (error, client) => {
        if(error) {
            return console.log('Error connecting to the server.')
        }

        console.log('Succesfully connected.')
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me, and no more errors.

```
mongoose
.connect(URL_of_mongodb, {
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useNewUrlParser: true,
})
.then(() => console.log('DB Connected!'))
.catch(err => {
console.log(`DB Connection Error: ${err}`);
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer! Also, don't forget to check this: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

> working sample code for mongo, [reference link](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_createcollection.asp)

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
MongoClient.connect(url,{ useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  dbo.createCollection("customers", function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Collection created!");
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are really helpful in knowing what needs to be done to get rid of the warning. But I did not find the answer to 'why'. One of the answers to [Warning on Connecting to MongoDB with a Node server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546635/warning-on-connecting-to-mongodb-with-a-node-server) points towards https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/tag/v3.2.1. Let me try summarizing it here. For more details you can visit the above link.

With v3.1.0 release, the 2.x driver got deprecated and completely rewritten. The rewrite introduces a new concept of Topology replacing the existing topology concepts like Mongos, ReplSet, and Server etc for better maintainability and traceability. One can enable this functionality by passing the flag useUnifiedTopology. The warning is to encourage users to try it out as soon as possible.

One more useful link which discusses this from NodeJS point of view: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/unified-topology/

Answer (score 1):

Those who having deprecation warning while using Mongoose with extensions like **multer-gridfs-storage**.

Since GridFS Storage calls your Mongoose constructor, you can pass the suggested option in the instance creation, to obtain inheritance.

```
new GridFsStorage({ options: { useUnifiedTopology: true }});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `winston`, you need `{ useUnifiedTopology: true }`

for example:

```
winston.add(
  new winston.transports.MongoDB({
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/vidly',
    level: 'error',
    options: { useUnifiedTopology: true },
  })
);
```

Comment: Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue:

1. I made sure to be connected to mongoDB by running the following on the terminal:

   ```
   brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
   ```

   And I got the output:

   ```
   Successfully started `mongodb-community`
   ```

Instructions for installing mongodb at 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGIcrMTtjoU

2. My configuration was as follows:

   ```
   mongoose.connect(config.mongo_uri, {
       useUnifiedTopology: true,
       useNewUrlParser: true})
       .then(() => console.log("Connected to Database"))
       .catch(err => console.error("An error has occured", err));
   ```

Which solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
   const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

   mongo.connect(process.env.DATABASE,{useUnifiedTopology: true, 
   useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, db) => {
      if(err) {
    console.log('Database error: ' + err);
   } else {
    console.log('Successful database connection');
      auth(app, db)
      routes(app, db)

   app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
      console.log("Listening on port " + process.env.PORT);
    });
```

}});

Answer (score 0):

Setting mongoose connect **useUnifiedTopology: true** option

```
  import mongoose from 'mongoose';

        const server = '127.0.0.1:27017'; // REPLACE WITH YOUR DB SERVER
        const database = 'DBName'; // REPLACE WITH YOUR DB NAME
        class Database {
          constructor() {
            this._connect();
          }
          _connect() {
            mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
            // * Local DB SERVER *
            mongoose
              .connect(`mongodb://${server}/${database}`, {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useCreateIndex: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true
              })
              .then(
                () => console.log(`mongoose version: ${mongoose.version}`),
                console.log('Database connection successful'),
              )
              .catch(err => console.error('Database connection error', err));   
          }
        }
        module.exports = new Database();
```

Answer (score 0):

**I want to add to this thread that it may also have to do with other dependencies.**

For instance, nothing I updated or set for NodeJS, MongoDB or Mongoose were the issue - however - `connect-mongodb-session` had been updated and starting slinging the same error. The solution, in this case, was to simply rollback the version of `connect-mongodb-session` from version `2.3.0` to `2.2.0`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i had the same errors popping up each time and this worked for me

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/${yourDB}", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true

}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("Database connection successful")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this line, this worked for me

```
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MongoDB server
then after using connect in the cluster clock on connect and finding the URL,
the URL will be somehing like this

```
<mongodb+srv://Rohan:<password>@cluster0-3kcv6.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority>
```

In this case, don't forget to replace the password with your database password and db name
and then use

```
const client = new MongoClient(url,{useUnifiedTopology:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect("DBURL", {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true },(err)=>{
    if(!err){
         console.log('MongoDB connection sucess');
        }
    else{ 
        console.log('connection not established :' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
    }
});
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple , remove the code that you have used and use the below code :

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
var dbConn = mongodb.MongoClient.connect(url, {useUnifiedTopology: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

if  you used typescript add config to the MongoOptions

```
const MongoOptions: MongoClientOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};

      const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, MongoOptions);

if you not used typescript  
const MongoOptions= {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
// Connect to Mongo
mongoose.set("useNewUrlParser", true);
mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);

mongoose
  .connect(db) // Connection String here
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected..."))
  .catch(() => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);
```

**Cut the upper 2nd line then Just Replace that's line**

```
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const DB = process.env.DATABASE;
mongoose.connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useCreateIndex: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    useFindAndModify: false
}).then(()=>{ 
    console.log("connection successful");
}).catch((err) =>{
    console.log("no connection");
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).