# Mongoose warns: DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When starting up my application, I get the following warning:

```
(node:11800) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and
Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future
version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass
option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

Yet we are specifying this value:

```
connection = await mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
  keepAlive: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

The value for `dbUrl` is: `mongodb://localhost:27017/test-app`

Environment:

- `mongo v4.0.13 on macOS`
- `nodejs v10.15.3`
- `package mongodb@3.3.2`
- `package mongoose@5.7.0`

Any ideas on how to deal with the warning?

Comment: I think this was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895175/server-discovery-and-monitoring-engine-is-deprecated

Comment: Apart from the above mentioned link which has it all. You can try setting it explicity by `mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);`

Comment: Turns out the issue was related to a piece of code in our tests that was using mongodb package directly, to drop the database. We needed to ensure the parameter was passed there.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to change in public ip address
The only way that worked for me is by changing my public ip address inside mongodb atlas
Go to cluster>network access>click on edit
then change the ip address with your current public ip address

for checking you ip address **type what is my public ip address on google and follow the first link**

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, and no more errors.

try this,

```
mongoose
    .connect(db,{
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        })
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```