# why i am not able view the fetched data from the data base in console

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Written the code which will fetch the data from the Mongo db and print in the console .But it is not displaying me any thing and getting stoped

**Console O/P -**

```
(node:85991) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
```

**Code**

```
const MongoClient = require ('mongodb');
const url = 'mongodb://10.142.206.22:27017/';
const databasename = 'snapp_transactions';  // Database name
MongoClient.connect (url).then ((client) => {

  const connect = client.db (databasename);

  // Connect to collection
  const collection = connect
    .collection ('redemptions');

  collection.find ({}).toArray ().then ((ans) => {
    console.log (ans);
  });
}).catch ((err) => {

  // Printing the error message
  console.log (err.Message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with mongoose;

```
mongoose.createConnection(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Or

```
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
```

Also please refer to this thread: [Server Discovery And Monitoring engine is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57895175/server-discovery-and-monitoring-engine-is-deprecated)

Comment: can you tell where to keep this line 

mongoose.createConnection(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

Comment: is that possible with out doing Mongoos

Comment: Sure, you have a lot of other options to connect to mongo. I recommend you have a look at their documentation for the connect() method https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/connect/

for your use case I guess it would look like

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });

Also a few good inputs are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448272/avoid-current-url-string-parser-is-deprecated-warning-by-setting-usenewurlpars