# So i have been trying to connect mongo and mongo-express an d been getting this error:

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker

YAML FILE
this is the YAML file

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
```

after composing it and using docker logs mongo-express I am getting this in my terminal

(node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: command listDatabases requires authentication
at Connection. (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:453:61)
at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
at processMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:456:10)
at Socket. (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:625:15)
at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: [How do I ask good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: Hi, about the warning, it's sounds like `mongo-express` doesn't add proper options when client is trying to init the connection (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57547013). For the promise rejection I can't reproduce your error. Did you try to re-pull your images ?
You can find some clues here : https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/issues/720